# Socket already opened issue when using Redis cache along with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, redis-cache

I am facing, "Error: Socket already opened issue" when I am using Redis along with my node.js project.

I am trying to cache database results into Redis cache.. When Redis key is not empty, I will pick records from Redis Key. When its empty, I will pick from DB and set to Redis Key.

Here is my code:

```
const { response } = require('express');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

function GetLatestPosts() {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        await client.connect();
        const value = await client.get('indexitems');
        if (value != null) {
            await client.disconnect();
            resolve(JSON.parse(value));
        }
        else {
            var PostsList;
            mysqldb.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                var sql = "CALL PRC_GetPostsList()";
                connection.query(sql, async function (err, data, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    PostsList = data[0];
                    await client.set('indexitems', JSON.stringify(PostsList));
                    await client.expire('indexitems', 86400);
                    await client.disconnect();
                    resolve(PostsList);  
                });
            });
        }
    })
}
```

I am facing "Error: Socket already opened issue" randomly. Some times it works without any issue. Some times it shows Error: Socket already opened.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Here is my complete error:

```
Error: Socket already opened
RedisSocket.connect (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:48:19)
Commander.connect (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:156:70)
/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/routes/index.js:224:22
new Promise (<anonymous>)
GetPostItems (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/routes/index.js:223:12)
/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/routes/index.js:23:29
Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
next (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/Projects/Site/Web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem occurs as `client.connect()` is called, whereas the redis client is already connected.

Whenever `client.get('indexitems')` returns a value, then the connection is correctly closed by `await client.disconnect();`

However, if there is no value, then an *asynchronous* call to mySQL is made, and the disconnection is only made in the callback of that request.

As this mySQL call happens asynchronously, the function `GetLatestPosts` may be executed again before the redis connection is closed, and `client.connect()` called a second time, provoking the error.

#### Solution

The connection to the redis client might be opened only once when the server starts, and kept opened.

This reduce the overhead of opening a new one at each request, then closing it.

The adapted code might then look like below:

```
const { response } = require('express');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

async function start() {

    await client.connect();

    function GetLatestPosts() {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
            const value = await client.get('indexitems');
            if (value != null) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(value));
            }
            else {
                var PostsList;
                mysqldb.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                    var sql = "CALL PRC_GetPostsList()";
                    connection.query(sql, async function (err, data, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        PostsList = data[0];
                        await client.set('indexitems', JSON.stringify(PostsList));
                        await client.expire('indexitems', 86400);
                        resolve(PostsList);  
                    });
                });
            }
        })
    }
}

start()
```

##### Extra remarks:

1. A [graceful shutdown](https://hackernoon.com/graceful-shutdown-in-nodejs-2f8f59d1c357) of the server might also be implemented, in order to close the connections to DB clients in a clean way.
2. Same goes for the mysql connection: it can be opened only once at server startup.
3. You might prefer to call `client.quit()` rather than `client.disconnect()`, in order to ensure that all commands get executed  - as [documented](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#Disconnecting).

Answer (score 1):

`npm install ioredis` works well for serverless applications rather than the native package.!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis

Comment: why do you say serverless. What do you mean?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew because it automatically manages connections rather than having to setup it up each time with native redis module. Its worked great for me so far